# SQLite encryption in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, sqlite, encryption, windows-phone-8

Can we encrypt the SQLite database in Windows Phone 8. I see there is SQLite Encryption Extension available but can we use it with WP8. If yes, how?

I have implemented SQLite as per [this post](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone)!.

Comment: Did you implement a solution for this? I'm looking into two solutions so far - one from [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/design) and a licensed sqlite [sqlite enc](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/see.html) solution as well. Curious if you went with one of them.

Comment: Hi jchristof, I implemented this using SEE. I wrote an article on it. Find it [here](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Compiling_and_using_SQLite_Encryption_Extension_(SEE)_with_Windows_Phone_8).